# pathconf( ) linux equivalent windows API

Tags: linux, windows, path

Can anyone suggest me the equivalent Windows API for Linux PathConf( ) API.

If I use MAX_PATH, it will be macro and that is 256.

Answer (score 2):

You should indeed use `MAX_PATH` on Windows, as it is not a configurable item on that platform.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath